# Gradle config to custom plugin

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to get a better understanding of what is possible to do with gradle plugins. I've done some reading on https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html, but
I do not feel like it answers my questions.

Right now we have several projects that are built into ear files with the ear-plugin.
However, for all our ear-projects we have a bunch of other config that we at the moment have in a company_ear.gradle file
that we apply in the build.gradle file of our ear-projects.

example of our company_ear.gradle:

```
allprojects {
  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {   
    sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
    targetCompatibility = "1.7" 
  }
}

apply plugin: 'ear'

ear {
  appDirName 'application'
  rename('([^-]*)(.*)(.war)', '$1$3')
  rename('([^-]*)(.*)(.jar)', '$1$3')
}

task devDeploy (type: Copy, dependsOn: assemble) {
  //code to do local deploy of ear
}

// More custom stuff that should apply to all ear-projects
```

So my question is, is it possible to move this to a custom gradle plugin so I can just do "apply plugin: company-ear"? I understand how to do the "devDeploy" task
in a plugin but I can not understand how I would fix the allProjects, apply plugin: 'ear', and ear-block in a custom plugin.

Comment: You can move all the code above into a Gradle plugin. The API used by a Gradle plugin is the same as the one used in the build script. The only difference is that you will have to work with the `Project` instance if you are writing a binary plugin.

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko, seems to almost be working. 

In my old file I have something like this:
    
    project.task buildPaa(type: Zip) {

That defines some files to add to a zip. But when I'm using this in my plugin I get an error from gradle saying that it can not find the property Zip. I've tried to change it to Zip.class but that does not change anything. Got any clue what I might do to fix this problem?

Comment: Managed to make it work by using org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip instead of just Zip and the import.